# Mysql Find numbers in string and filter result by numbers in string

Tags: mysql

I have mysql table with has field product_name which has data something like

```
SKL-05
TIP-01
TIP-02 L/R
TIP-12 UV
TIP-120 L/R
TIP-121 L/R
TIP-13 L/R
```

I want to sort that result like as follow

```
SKL-05
TIP-01
TIP-02 L/R
TIP-12 UV
TIP-13 L/R
TIP-120 L/R
TIP-121 L/R
```

Means numberwise in the string 01, 02, 03 etc
Please help me guys...

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Use `substring()` function to strip off the first characters.

Comment: `ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(product_name,5),' ',1) AS INT)` might work.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT product_name FROM table1 
ORDER BY substring(product_name FROM 5)
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

This will kill any index you have on product_name though, if you need speed, add an extra field `numeric_product_name` with an index on that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `SUBSTRING()` and `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` functions of MySQL: **[String functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)**

Try:

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING(product_name,5),' ',1) AS INT)
```

or

```
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(product_name,' ',1),'-',-1) AS INT)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options:

1. Reformat the codes to allow them to be ordered naturally, eg.

   ```
    TIP-121 L/R     -->  TIP-121 L/R
    TIP-13 L/R      -->  TIP-013 L/R
   ```
2. Split the string up into its parts and order on them individually. This can get a bit horrible if there are lots of parts. eg.

   ```
   SELECT code
   FROM table
   ORDER BY 
       SUBSTR(code, 1, 4), 
       CAST(SUBSTR(code, 5, LOCATE(' ', code)) AS UNSIGNED)
   ```